# how to interact Vulkan with Android Java Activity

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan, native-activity

Currently, android Vulkan only supports NativeActivity, but is there any way we can use Java Activity and SurfaceView or any other view and pass Native through JNI to get NativeWindow handler.

I tried looking around and link my surface view but it didn't work for me, any sample code or example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any sample code off-hand, but if you have a `SurfaceView` you want to get the `Surface` from it, and from that you can get (in C) the `ANativeWindow` for creating the `VkSurfaceKHR`/`VkSwapchainKHR`. The sequence is something like:

Java: `surface = surfaceView->getHolder()->getSurface();`

Pass surface to a JNI call into C as a `jobject`.

C: `window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, jsurface);`

That function is declared in the NDK `android/native_window_jni.h` header.

You'll want to register callbacks with the `SurfaceView`'s `SurfaceHolder` and manage the window lifecycle (which is tied to the Activity lifecycle) correctly.

Comment: On top of this, it's probably also worth looking at what glSurfaceView does (it's open source) to manage rendering on a thread other than the main UI thread and to handle any resizing, etc. In my projects I've created a vkSurfaceView which is like a simplified glSurfaceView. Really, google ought to supply a workable vkSurfaceView implementation.

Comment: Hi, This SO answer shows basic setup needed to implement VulkanSurfaceView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60706911/1418981